# how to fix ValueError: Fan in and fan out can not be computed for tensor with fewer than 2 dimensions

Tags: pytorch, pre-trained-model

I am trying to initialize weight with xavier, but have this error. How to fix?

```py
net = resnet50(weights=None)
# change the weights (leave biases as Kaiming [default])
    for p in net.named_parameters():
        if 'weight' in p[0]:
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(p[1].data)

    num_classes = len(train_dataset.classes)
    # Parameters of newly constructed modules have requires_grad=True by default
    net.fc = nn.Linear(net.fc.in_features, num_classes)
    model_ft = net.to(device)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 7
      5 for p in net.named_parameters():
      6     if 'weight' in p[0]:
----> 7         nn.init.xavier_normal_(p[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

you should check out the document of xavier_normal_

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html?highlight=xavier_normal_#torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_

according to the formula of torch, which needs two arguments.

if the tensor only has one dimension, it will raises the error.

So when one tensor only has one dimension, you should use another method to initialize. like **torch.randn()** or **nn.init.normal_()**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Xavier initialization makes use of the *fan-in* and *fan-out* of a layer (no. of inputs and no. of outputs of the layer) to initialize its weights, and in the case of Pytorch, the inizialization method defines these numbers using the shapes of the weight matrices.

As the error states, there are weight matrices with less than 2 dimensions in ResNet50, making it impossible to determine the corresponding fan-in and fan-out.

Looking at the names of the parameters of the network, we find out that the 1-dimensional weight matrices correspond to the `gamma` vectors associated with the `BatchNormalization` modules:

```py
for p in net.named_parameters():
    print(p[0], p[1].shape)
```

```
conv1.weight torch.Size([64, 3, 7, 7])
bn1.weight torch.Size([64])
bn1.bias torch.Size([64])
layer1.0.conv1.weight torch.Size([64, 64, 1, 1])
layer1.0.bn1.weight torch.Size([64])
...
```

In fact, as stated by the original ResNet [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385), the authors applied batch normalization after each convolution and before activation.

Hence, for the initialization we should avoid the BN scaling vectors, and focus only on convolutional and linear layers:

```py
for module in net.modules():
    if isinstance(module, nn.Conv2d):
        init.xavier_normal_(module.weight)
    elif isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
        init.xavier_normal_(module.weight)
```

This code will apply the Xavier normal initialization to the weights of all the convolutional and linear layers in the network, avoiding the batch normalization parameters.

You can add additional conditions if you need to use this initialization technique only for weights related to specific modules (e.g. only inside residual blocks).